# STM32F103 bxCAN not working

Tags: stm32, c, can, hal

I'm trying to make use of the bxCAN of STM32F103C8 on a bluepill but it doesn't work and I don't know what is the problem.I'm using the hal API
here is the main code in the while loop

```
while (1)
{
    char msg[50];
    CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef TxHeader;
    uint8_t data[5] = {'H','E','L','L','O'};
    uint32_t TxMailbox;
    TxHeader.DLC = 5;
    TxHeader.ExtId = 0x18181820;
    TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_EXT;
    TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    if(HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, data,TxMailbox) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
    }

    while(HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan, TxMailbox));
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
}
```

The code breaks at the HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage.
this is my first time working with an STM32 so I've never had a working example and couldn't find any working examples online.
Please help I've posted many times :/

Comment: How are you initialising bxCAN and how many CAN nodes does your network have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TxMailbox` -> `&TxMailbox`.

The manual:

> `pTxMailbox`  pointer to a variable where the function will return the TxMailbox used to store the Tx message.

Since the function will apparently try to return data through this pointer, it will crash and burn if you provide a `uint32_t` by value.

Notably, a conforming C compiler must give you a message (warning or error) for this code. If you didn't get any such message, your tool chain is broken. [References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).